# Add extra column to a list of .txt files based on keywords

Tags: r, file, filenames

I have a list of 100 text files that have values of temperature belonging to each station in the UK. However, I have no way of distinguishing them in a loop besides by manual work.

I wish for them to be detected by keywords, and then attribute a column vector by the selected name, for example:

```
EUROPEAN CLIMATE ASSESSMENT & DATASET (ECA&D), file created on 25-06-2021
THESE DATA CAN BE USED FREELY PROVIDED THAT THE FOLLOWING SOURCE IS ACKNOWLEDGED:

Klein Tank, A.M.G. and Coauthors, 2002. Daily dataset of 20th-century surface
air temperature and precipitation series for the European Climate Assessment.
Int. J. of Climatol., 22, 1441-1453.
Data and metadata available at http://www.ecad.eu

FILE FORMAT (MISSING VALUE CODE IS -9999):

01-06 SOUID: Source identifier
08-15 DATE : Date YYYYMMDD
17-21 TX   : maximum temperature in 0.1 &#176;C
23-27 Q_TX : Quality code for TX (0='valid'; 1='suspect'; 9='missing')

This is the blended series of station UNITED KINGDOM, ARMAGH (STAID: 271).
Blended and updated with sources: 100918 146805 
See file sources.txt and stations.txt for more info.

SOUID,    DATE,   TX, Q_TX
146805,18440101,   19,    0
146805,18440102,   -2,    0
146805,18440103,   67,    0
146805,18440104,  111,    0
146805,18440105,  117,    0
146805,18440106,   89,    0
146805,18440107,   61,    0
146805,18440108,   69,    0

#Expected:
SOUID,    DATE,   TX, Q_TX    Station
146805,18440101,   19,    0   ARMAGH
146805,18440102,   -2,    0   ARMAGH
146805,18440103,   67,    0   ARMAGH
146805,18440104,  111,    0   ARMAGH
146805,18440105,  117,    0   ARMAGH
146805,18440106,   89,    0   ARMAGH
146805,18440107,   61,    0   ARMAGH 
146805,18440108,   69,    0   ARMAGH
```

I can select the list of files using:

```
files <- list.files(pattern = ".txt", full.names=TRUE)
all.txt <- lapply(files, data.table::fread)
```

However, `fread` removes the header so I have no way of identifying which Station they belong to.

How can I create a new column based on the station in the text, if I have a list of station names available tat I can match them to?

Update:

I have managed to read the text file into `read_table`, then extract the stations names that come after Kingdom, however those names with white spaces, only the first word is select. Given that that the station name is at the end of the row after United Kingdom, then selecting the rest of the words after KINGDOM would work.

Here is what I tried so far:

```
stringr::str_extract(xp1$xp, '(?<=KINGDOM\\s)\\w+')
```

Which would fail if I had e.g. `Cex et England`, I only get `Cex`

Comment: Do you mean the content of txt file is like `This is only an example of the header to each text file blah blah blah 
Bu this station is called ARMAGH

SOUID,    DATE,   TX, Q_TX
146805,18440101,   19,    0
146805,18440102,   -2,    0 ……`? I guess you can extract the key word with Regular Expression.

Comment: @PeaceWang Regular Expression has always been my weakness however this is a good time to brush up on my skills for it

Comment: If your file has so much of text before actual data, does `fread` give you an error?

Comment: @RonakShah `fread` just cuts off the content but leaves the data, so It definitely is not the best choice. I am trying to use `read_table` that captures the text file into one column, and figuring out some Regrex (Which is my weakness) to extract the station names that come after `UNITED KINGDOM`, store it as a vector, because now the vector station names are in order relative to the list,  remove the content, then split the data into their respective columns, and add the new names using something like `cbind`. This approach is a slight stretch for me and fairly long to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex to extract the word occurring after `.*UNITED KINGDOM,`  in the file and use it as station name.

```
library(data.table)

all.txt <- lapply(files, function(x) transform(fread(x), 
                 Station = sub('.*UNITED KINGDOM, (.*?)\\(.*', '\\1',
                           paste0(readLines(x), collapse = '\n'))))
```

Comment: "ARMAGH" is a station name in one of the files identifying which station the data is from, however each text file has a unique station so "ARMAGH" only belongs to one text file. Unfortunately, I cannot use the file names as they are gibberish. I have a list of the stations names as a variable, however I am not so sure on how this can be used to identify the station name in the text file. Each text file has a unique station name, and it only appears once

Comment: The problem with this is that the vector with names are unordered, as are the text files so they would be mismatching. Unless their is a way to match the station name in the content of the text, with the vector?

Comment: You ask good questions and it were my fault for not making my question clearer. I have updated the text file above, please have it look. The station names always come after the text "UNITED KINGDOM"

Comment: That is definitely in the right direction! However, look at my updated text in the question. I have the same problem with this code! Perhaps picking all the words after `KINGDOM` and before `(`?